# Simple Error Trap in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

Using GCC, I am trying to add simple exception logic to this program.  Ideally, a simple "if" would work well.  IF the `fopen` succeeds then do x, if it fails do z.  Is there a simple way to do this?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  FILE *ptr;
  ptr = fopen("c:\\RedyBoot.bat","r");
  fclose(ptr);
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: In C, most system and standard library functions have a specific error code that they will return when they fail, and then they will set the global variable `errno` to a number that specifies exactly what went wrong. The documentation for each function should say what the error code is, and what the `errno` values are.

Answer (score 3):

...

[If `fopen` fails, it will return NULL](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html#tag_03_176_04), so

```
if (ptr == NULL) {
  do z;
} else {
  do x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that and report also the error message:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  FILE *handle;
  errno = 0;                     
  handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open file %s, error: %s",
             "file.txt", strerror (errno));
    exit (-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: But it would be even better with: `const char fname[] = "file.txt";` and using fname in the two function calls.  It's a form of DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: Common.. the objective of the code was to quickly show how to handle and show the error, not a book about C patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this to check the condition and print an error if the condition is not met:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(x) \
    do { \
        if (!(x)) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __func__, __LINE__); \
            perror(#x); \
            exit(-1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");
    CHECK(NULL != file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```